# What exactly is the right approach when trying to find OOS MSE when using linear lasso regression?

Tags: self-study, cross-validation, model-selection, lasso

This isn't a question where I have a code example to provide. It is more of an informal question about what to do between 2 options.

Assume I have some data and my goal is to fit a model using the lasso algorithm and I want to select a model based on the OOS MSE score. Which of the 2 approaches below is correct?

- Split my data into training data and test data, cross validate using the training data, and then pick the model with the lowest MSE on the test data.
- Do not split the data and instead just use the cross validation on all the data and extract the MSE from this (I thought that maybe because during cross validation we already kind of split the data into folds and so the MSE might actually be a kind of estimate of the OOS MSE).

I'm not quite sure which approach to take so any guidance would be great.

Comment: The conventional paradigm is to split into train and test data, and then pick the model (and tune hyperparameters such as the LASSO regularisation/penalisation factor) using cross-validation on the training set, train this model on the full training set, and finally test it on the test set to measure out-of-sample error (you have already chosen your model and hyperparameters).

Comment: Great, thank you so much!

Comment: @Henry why not post that as an answer?